# C# Automatic generate method callbacks on runtime?

Tags: c#, runtime, ilgenerator

I want to bind a runtime method to a class method (if i invoke the runtime method, it must call my class method, with or without parameters and return value).

My code works if I do not set a parameter on the invoke method and Callback method, but, if I set parameters, I got the error: "give error Parameter count mismatch.": how con I fix it?

```
    public class RunNow
{
    public void Run(string hoo)
    {

    }

    public void Callback(string ali)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("yessss");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RunNow run = new CSMethodInjection.RunNow();
        var methodToCall = run.GetType().GetMethod("Callback");
        var t = GenerateType(run.GetType().Name, methodToCall);
        if (t != null)
        {
            object o = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
            MethodInfo helloWorld = t.GetMethod(methodToCall.Name);
            if (helloWorld != null)
            {
                helloWorld.Invoke(o, new object[] { "aaaaa" });//give error Parameter count mismatch.
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static Type GenerateType(string className, MethodInfo toCall)
    {
        AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        AssemblyName assemName = new AssemblyName();
        assemName.Name = "InjectionAssembly";

        AssemblyBuilder assemBuilder = currentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(assemName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);

        ModuleBuilder moduleBuilder = assemBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("InjectionModule");

        TypeBuilder typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType(className, TypeAttributes.Public);
        MethodBuilder methodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(toCall.Name, MethodAttributes.Public, null, null);
        List<Type> parameters = new List<Type>();
        foreach (var item in toCall.GetParameters())
        {
            parameters.Add(item.ParameterType);
            var pBuilder = methodBuilder.DefineParameter(item.Position, item.Attributes, item.Name);

        }

        if (parameters.Count > 0)
            methodBuilder.SetParameters(parameters.ToArray());
        methodBuilder.SetReturnType(toCall.ReturnType);
        ILGenerator msilG = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();
        msilG.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        msilG.Emit(OpCodes.Call, toCall);
        msilG.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        return typeBuilder.CreateType();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you try my answer? Please **edit** your question to let me know if you still have issues, **after** applying the code changes I suggested below. thanks for your consideration :)

Comment: thank you for answer it's works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the count error, you can *delete or comment out your foreach wrongly populating the parameters list and* **do** instead

```
 MethodBuilder methodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(toCall.Name, 
     MethodAttributes.Public,
     toCall.ReturnType, 
     toCall.GetParameters().Select(x => x.ParameterType).ToArray());
```

Then you still have other problems in your generator,
we can simplify it by the following

```
ILGenerator msilG = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();
msilG.EmitWriteLine("Hello World"); // or much better see below
msilG.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
return typeBuilder.CreateType();
```

or, **much better**, replace my above `msilG.EmitWriteLine("Hello World");` with

```
msilG.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
msilG.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1); // it's cool, isn't it?
msilG.Emit(OpCodes.Call, toCall);
```

finally you can also adapt the callback ;)

```
public void Callback(string ali)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ali); // let me see "aaaaa"
}
```

Comment: I've just finished editing the last details. This is tested and working, so I hope you can *accept* my answer... anyway, let me know should any issues arise...